# Execute Javascript on external url using HybridView, Xamarin cross platform

Tags: javascript, c#, xamarin, webview

I have tried to execute JavaScript on an external url (ie: http://facebook.com) using WebView from Visual Studio Mac 2019, and so far no results.

To do so, I have tried to follow along with the official tutorial here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview, and also tried a simpler one here: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-webview-executing-javascript/

Here is what I did with explanations:

On my shared folder, I created an HybridWebView class with the following code:

```
    public class HybridWebView : WebView
{



    Action<string> action;


    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Uri",
        returnType: typeof(Func<string, Task<string>>),
        declaringType: typeof(HybridWebView),
        defaultValue: default(string));


    public string Uri
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(UriProperty);
        set
        {
            SetValue(UriProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public void RegisterAction(Action<string> callback)
    {
        action = callback;
    }

    public void Cleanup()
    {
        action = null;
    }

    public void InvokeAction(string data)
    {
        if (action == null || data == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        action.Invoke(data);
    }



    public Func<string, Task<string>> ExecuteJavascript
    {
        get { return (Func<string, Task<string>>)GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

From The macOS project which I use to test my cross-platform app, I tried the following custom renderer:

```
public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, WKWebView>
{


    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var webView = e.NewElement as HybridWebView;

        if (webView != null)
        {
            Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(Element.ExecuteJavascript.ToString())));
        }

    }

}
```

To note that the following part wouldn't work:

```
var webView = e.NewElement as HybridWebView; 
if (webView != null)
    webView.ExecuteJavascript = (js) =>
    {
        return Task.FromResult(this.ExecuteJavascript(js)); // issue at ExecuteJavascript with following error ('HybridWebViewRenderer' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteJavascript' ), hence replaced by Control.LoadRequest ...
    };
```

From my ViewModel, I did the following:

```
 public Func<string, Task<string>> EvaluateJavascript { get; set; }

        public async Task OnConnectTapped()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("on connect tapped");
        // passing the url onto a connection service
        var hybridWebView = new HybridWebView
        {
            Uri = "https://facebook.com/"
        };

        //hybridWebView.InvokeAction("document.getElementById('td');");
        //var result = await hybridWebView.RegisterAction(data => DisplayAlert("Alert", "Hello " + data, "OK"));
        var result = await hybridWebView.ExecuteJavascript("document.cookie;");

        Console.WriteLine("result is {0}", result);
    }
```

Here is the error when trying to execute my code:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at MyApp.ViewModel.MainModel.OnConnectTapped () [0x00031] in .../../././/ViewModel/MainModel.cs:451
  at .......<.ctor>g__c5|48_9 () [0x0001f] in /../../../.cs:143
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1021
  at Foundation.NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher.Apply () [0x00002] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/6.6.0.12/src/Xamarin.Mac/Foundation/NSAction.cs:178
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) AppKit.NSApplication.NSApplicationMain(int,string[])
  at AppKit.NSApplication.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00040] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/6.6.0.12/src/Xamarin.Mac/AppKit/NSApplication.cs:100
  at redacted.macOS.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00017] in /Users/dom-bruise/Projects/redacted/redacted.macOS/Main.cs:11
```

For me, it could either be because I can't execute external pages, or the part where I replaced by the following messing up my attempt.

```
if (webView != null)
{
    Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(Element.ExecuteJavascript.ToString())));
}
```

My main goal here is to have my app execute JavaScript underneath the hood on pages using WebView, and fill in forms automatically calling back C# from my app.

Comment: Try to use `WebRednerer` instead of `ViewRenderer`  , if problem persists , consider raising issue : https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: Hi. I'll try tomorrow and we'll keep you updated.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi. I remembered that I tried it before, and it gave an error on OnElementChanged line with the following:

'HybridWebViewRenderer.OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView>)': no suitable method found to override

Same goes if I change  ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView>) to ElementChangedEventArgs<WebViewRenderer>).

Getting a working example from someone who did this from macOS would be great.